# How to get a specific value from json

Tags: javascript, json, webloadui

How to retrieve value from json using webload javascript

```
Message: keys value is : {"_Success": 1, "Criteria": "1234", "SearchAndSelect":  [ {"DateOfBirth": 
"15/02/1962","EmpNo": "123456","LastName": "John", "FirstName": "Smith", "Reference": "1234", "Keys": 
"5eac0bbd-82d7-4959-8496-2cdb13dea292" } ]  }
```

I want to retrieve the value of Keys

"Keys": "5eac0bbd-82d7-4959-8496-2cdb13dea292"

Comment: Firstly the JSON needs parsing `JSON.parse(JSONText)`. Then you can use JavaScript dot/square bracket notation to access the property.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(json);

var keys = jsonParsed.SearchAndSelect[0].Keys;

console.log(keys); // "5eac0bbd-82d7-4959-8496-2cdb13dea292"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```js
JSON.parse(`{"_Success": 1, "Criteria": "1234", "SearchAndSelect":  [ {"DateOfBirth": 
"15/02/1962","EmpNo": "123456","LastName": "John", "FirstName": "Smith", "Reference": "1234", "Keys": 
"5eac0bbd-82d7-4959-8496-2cdb13dea292" } ]  }`)
```

Comment: I think you mean to pass a string into `JSON.parse`. Otherwise this will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

SearchAndSelect is the Key of the JSON which you should search in. It is a List of JSONS
so in case you are using javascript you would do something like this

```
let data = JSON.parse(result)

for(let element of data.SearchAndSelect){
    console.log(element.Keys)
}
```

This handles in case there are multiple values in SearchAndSelect Array

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {"_Success": 1, "Criteria": "1234", "SearchAndSelect":  [ {"DateOfBirth": 
        "15/02/1962","EmpNo": "123456","LastName": "John", "FirstName": "Smith", "Reference": "1234", "Keys": 
        "5eac0bbd-82d7-4959-8496-2cdb13dea292" } ]  };

    for (const property of data['SearchAndSelect']) {
          console.log(property['Keys']);
    }
```