# Console.log json specific value

Tags: json, console.log

I'm working with some script and I would like to ask how to display on the console a specific json value.

For example, I have script:

```
Promise.all([
  fetch('https://blockchain.info/balance?active=3C6WPNa5zNQjYi2RfRmt9WUVux7V4xbDmo').then(resp => resp.json()),
  fetch('https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCEUR').then(resp => resp.json()),
]).then(console.log)
```

output:

```
[{
    3C6WPNa5zNQjYi2RfRmt9WUVux7V4xbDmo: {
      final_balance: 185653,
      n_tx: 1,
      total_received: 185653
    }
  }, {
    mins: 5,
    price: "19230.49330261"
  }]
```

I want to console price and final_balance.
Best regards!

Comment: Did you see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66332707/18609846)

Answer (score 0):

One way you could achieve this is by flattening the array and objects within because there's no predefined structure of what the output looks like.

Here, I'm assuming the `output` you mentioned is always an array of objects.

```js
const flattenObject = (obj = {}) =>
  Object.keys(obj || {}).reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (typeof obj[cur] === "object") {
      acc = { ...acc, ...flattenObject(obj[cur]) };
    } else {
      acc[cur] = obj[cur];
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});

const outputs = [
  {
    "3C6WPNa5zNQjYi2RfRmt9WUVux7V4xbDmo": {
      final_balance: 185653,
      n_tx: 1,
      total_received: 185653,
    },
  },
  {
    mins: 5,
    price: "19230.49330261",
  },
];

outputs.forEach((output) => {
  const flatOutput = flattenObject(output);
  console.log("flatOutput:", flatOutput);
  if (flatOutput.final_balance) {
    console.log("final_balance:", flatOutput.final_balance);
  }
  if (flatOutput.price) {
    console.log("price:", flatOutput.price);
  }
});
```